# Android app is not installed on emulator or device when I run it in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, launchimage

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am testing my app running on both device and emulator. This is my third android app development. When I developed other apps, app is automatically installed with launch icon on device or on emulator. But when I run my currently developing app, it is successfully run on both emulator or device.

But app is not installed with launch icon. I did not modify and settings to Android Studio. I am using Android Studio version 1.4. Now I need to check the launch icon and other related things. But I cannot check it, because I cannot see launch icon installed.

What is the possible error? How can I make my app installed with launch icon once I run it?

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name="com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.model.Config"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity android:name=".InitialActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Is the app visible in the android application manager?

Comment: You mean in android manifest file?

Comment: Post your manifest file. And I would recommend you to update your Android Studio to 2.x version. There are some major updates related to the security flaws in the old version.

Comment: I already added it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tags to make an activity, a launcher activity should be inside [intent-filter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) tag. You missed that. The correct way should be:

```
<activity android:name=".InitialActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Happy to help ... :)